Build failed in Flutter for adding sqflite in the project : sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
I am having issue with sqflite in flutter.
I installed the sqflite package. And my code didnt have any issue. But when i ran it, it faced this problem
The error i am having is:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Hasnat Bin Sayed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Hasnat Bin Sayed\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Hasnat Bin Sayed\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

My build.gradle file:
plugins {

    id "com.android.application"

    id "kotlin-android"

    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.

    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"

}



android {

    namespace = "com.example.note_app_day4"

    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion

    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion



    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }



    kotlinOptions {

        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }



    defaultConfig {

        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).

        applicationId = "com.example.note_app_day4"

        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.

        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.

        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion

        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode = flutter.versionCode

        versionName = flutter.versionName

    }



    buildTypes {

        release {

            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.

            // Signing with the debug keys for 

I am a beginner. So i have tried clearing invalidate cache and restarting android studio. What to do?

This is a general solution for this type of errors that have appeared with recent android studio and flutter updates.
Modify android>settings.gradle file with this =
id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
Modify android>gradle>gradle-wrapper.properties file with this => distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip
